# AngularJS Set Property In Event Wait For $Http

Tags: angularjs, ajax, wijmo

I am using a the wijmo angularjs treeview

I want to be able to set a property inside a fired event based on the result of a $http request, But the event completes firing

```
     $scope.Drop = function (s, e) {            
        $http({
            url: NavMenuSelectionFac.AjaxURL("DeviceInstance/DeviceInstance/MoveDeviceInstance"),
            cache: false,
            method: 'POST',
            data: { "deviceInstanceToMove": e._src.dataItem, "NewParentPK": e._tgt.dataItem.pk },
            responseType: 'JSON',
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.Result === 1) {
                Notification.success(response.data.Message);  
                e.cancel = false;
                //This needs to be set based off the result of the http request
            }
            else {
                Notification.error(response.data.Message);
                e.cancel = true;

            }
        }, function (response) {
            //TODO : Something here
        });
    };
```

Comment: I'm not sure that what you are trying to accomplish here will work.  the event is synchronous, but `$http` is asynchronous.  you can't make the event wait for the result without causing the UI to be frozen until the response is returned, which is exactly what async methods were developed to avoid.

Comment: @Claies I though as much, I was trying to verify a drag and drop operation was successfully moved server side, and then allow or cancel the move on client side

Comment: Similar issue has been replied at the following link:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625929/wijmo-wj-tree-view-angularjs-drop-wait-for-http-callback/49006543#49006543](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625929/wijmo-wj-tree-view-angularjs-drop-wait-for-http-callback/49006543#49006543)